# Getting negative time duration in simulation in r

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, simulation

I have a dataset like this, which we have the age of the cases, their status, data_entry : time their entered, and date_end.

```
set.seed(123)
date_entry<- sample(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2010-01-01'), by="day"), 1000)
age <- sample(seq(as.Date('1930-01-01'), as.Date('1970-01-01'), by="day"), 1000)
status <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
df <- data.frame( date_entry, age, status)
df <- df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% rowwise %>% 
  mutate(date_end = sample(seq(date_entry, Sys.Date(), by="day"), 1))
```

I want to simulate date entry for status==1 to increase their mean of date_entery.

```
df$date_sim <- df$date_entry - df$status * round(rnorm(nrow(df), -400, 500))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x    = factor(status), 
             y    = as.numeric(difftime(date_sim, age, unit = 'w'))/52,
             fill = factor(status))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.6) +
  guides(fill = guide_none()) +
  labs(x = 'Status', y = 'Age (years)')
```

However, after simulation, several cases will have negative time duration which means their simulate time(date_sim) was after date_end.

```
df$time_duration= df$date_end-df$date_sim
df %>% 
  filter(time_duration<0)
```

How can I avoid these for those who have a short time duration of (date_end-df$date_sim?

So I need limit the simulation for those who had a short time_duration.

Comment: simulate some sample values for the number of days from `date_sim` and then add them to `date_sim` to get `date_end` -> `mutate(time_diff = as.numeric(sample(Sys.Date() - date_entry),1 ))`

Comment: Could you please explain more, I did not get your method.

Comment: Your `round(rnorm(nrow(df), -400, 500))` is mostly negative but often positive, leading to implausible time durations. (e.g. try running `max(round(rnorm(1000, -400, 500)))` a few times). Either use a different distribution which is bounded to one sign, or clamp it with something like `round(pmin(0,rnorm(nrow(df), -400, 500))))` which will change all positives to zero.

Comment: It seems I have still negative time duration. I need to limit or customize date_sim that passed the  date_entry.  This happend when date_entry and date_end are closed.

Comment: you can sample from say `sample(3000)` that will fetch random numbers from 1 to 3000. Let your `date_end` then be `date_entry` plus this random number. So `df %>% mutate(date_end = date_entry + sample(some_number, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)`. This way your date_end will always be greater than date_entry

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. My date_end is accurate , and I do not need to simulate it. I just want to simulate date_entry.